# Mysql: compare values from two columns in one table

Tags: mysql

I have a table like that:

```
ID|col1|col2
1 |a . |e
2 |b . |b
3 |c . |x
4 |d . |x
5 |e . |y
```

And now I want all rows where a value exists in col 1 and 2.

```
1 because e exists in col 1 and 2
2 because b exists in col 1 and 2
5 because e exists in col 1 and 2
```

Any idea? All solutions I found are solution for matching of two tables with a join. 
Thank you.

Comment: *a exists in col 2*? Where?

Comment: That's a flat out lie. Have you thought of going in to politics?

Comment: @forpas and Strawberry: You're right. I have corrected it.

Comment: a does not exist in col2 so 1 should not be in the results. So your question is still unclear.

Comment: @forpas: You're right again. I hope my problem is now more clear. Sorry for the circumstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for a self-join like below:

```
Select t.*
from mytable t
inner join mytable t2 on t.col1=t2.col2
```

Alternatively, you can use "IN" keyword like:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.col1 in (select col2 from mytable)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, but not sure, if this is the most efficient solution:

```
select * from mytable
where col2 in (select col1 from mytable)
OR col1 in (select col2 from mytable)
```